# Python List Slicing with None as argument

Tags: python, list, slice, nonetype

Via trial and error I found out that

```
my_list = range(10)
my_list[:None] == my_list[:]
```

I use this for django query sets so I can define a size or take all:

```
some_queryset[:length if length else None]

# @IanAuld
some_queryset[:length or None]


# @Bakuriu
# length works for all numbers and None if you want all elements
# does not work with False of any other False values
some_queryset[:length]
```

- Is this good practice to use `None` while slicing?
- Can problems occur with this method in any case?

Comment: If `length = 0` (asking for a queryset of length 0), you will receive quite an unexpected result by getting everything.

Comment: BTW, even `my_list[None:None] == my_list[:]` is `True`!

Comment: @IanAuld yes i do know that ;-) but i think its save to say that there is no use case for an empty list.

Comment: Please use `length` instead of `lenght`.

Comment: @yamm As long as you sure `0` will never be an acceptable value for `length` then it should work fine. Although it can be shortened to `lst[:length or None]`

Comment: Wait, I don't really get why you're doing this. I mean, can't you simply use `some_queryset[:length]`? As Ian pointed out if `length` is `0` and you actually *want* a zero length (strange case, but there are situations where you want that) the `length or None` expression has the wrong value and fixing it is "hard". You should just default the value of `length` to `None` and be done.

Comment: @Bakuriu yes ok. thats right (you opened my mind^). the only advantage of my way is that it also supports `''`,`[]`,`{}`,`()` and `False` as arguments. But you are totally right. The problem is that i normally use `False` as default and thats why i searched for a ways to do this with false. I came up with this by accident so its probably not the best way.

Comment: That's why you generally want to use `None` as a default value in Python. Also note that `None` is considered a false value, so it behaves almost exactly as `False`, but is generally more convenient. Use `False` if you actually need a boolean. Also, it doesn't make sense to pass `''` or `()` as a `length`. So it's a *good thing* that an exception is raised in that case because it probably means that the programmer has a bug in their code somewhere.

Comment: @Bakuriu i updated my question. good input ;-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to use `None`, as its behavior is specified by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

> The slice of s from i to j is defined as the sequence of items with index k such that i <= k < j. If i or j is greater than len(s), use len(s). If i is omitted or None, use 0. **If j is omitted or None, use len(s)**. If i is greater than or equal to j, the slice is empty.

Using `None` for one of the slice parameters is the same as omitting it.

Comment: Also note the error message when you specify an invalid slice index: `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`

Answer (score 6):

Your way is fine, but I would *prefer* :

```
some_queryset[:length] if length else some_queryset
```

or

```
some_queryset[:length] if length else some_queryset[:]
```

which are readable with less knowledge of how slicing treats these special cases.

Comment: which can also be written `length and some_queryset[:length] or some_queryset`

Answer (score 5):

It should be safe. In Python, `something[<sliceexpr>]` is equivalent to `something[slice(...)]`, and the documentation for the `slice` type clearly indicates that the arguments for stop and step default to `None`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between using `None` or using empty slicing like `[:]` but using `None` is useful when you want to use it within a list comprehension or use it under a condition for slicing, for example :

```
>>> [my_list[:length if length%2==0 else None] for length in [1,2,3]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

From a comment in `CPython` source [about slice function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/661cdbd617b8/Doc/c-api/slice.rst#l22) :

> Return a new slice object with the given values.  The *start*,
>   *stop*, and    *step* parameters are used as the values of the slice object attributes of    the same names.  Any of the values may be
>   *NULL*, in which case the    `None` will be used for the corresponding attribute.  Return *NULL* if    the new object could not
>   be allocated.

Answer (score 2):

As answer by @kasravnd describes, using None is same as not specifying anything in slice operator (i.e. it means *all*) but it is useful feature in case you want to conditionally specify an index or *all*.

However, there is also another use of None but it applies only to Numpy and Pytorch: You can use None in slice operator to add additional dimension to array.

```
import numpy as np

abc=np.array([1,2,3])
print(abc[:,None])
```

This prints:

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```