# Why do my_list[None:] and my_list[:None] return my_list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing a function today to do this:

```
def foo(n=None):
    my_list = generate_some_data()
    return my_list if n is None else my_list[:n]
```

So I wondered what would happen if `n` was `None` and I did `my_list[:n]`. So I opened a REPL and found this:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> my_list[:4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> my_list[:None]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> my_list[None:]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> my_list[None:None]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Why is this? What is going on under the covers that index `None` doesn't matter and it doesn't even raise an error?

Comment: You have your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622809/python-list-slicing-with-none-as-argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `my_list[:]` creates a copy of the list. `my_list[:None]` or `my_list[None:]` or `myList[None:None]` are equivalent to `my_list[:]`.

This iPython session should show what I'm talking about:

```
In [73]: myList = [1, 2, 3]

In [74]: myListReference = myList

In [75]: myList is myListReference
Out[75]: True

In [76]: myList == myListReference
Out[76]: True

In [77]: myList is myList[:]
Out[77]: False

In [78]: myList == myList[:]
Out[78]: True

In [79]: myList is myList[:None]
Out[79]: False

In [80]: myList == myList[:None]
Out[80]: True
```

This is called the "shallow copy" operator. This allows you to modify a copy of a list without modifying the original.